# Azure Cognitive Services Content Moderation can't find some simple stopwords

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Content moderation api for text fails recognizing simple drugs term as "cocaine" and other simple profanities. It seems to work only on a very limited set of profanities.

I'm using the Web GUI with my resouce key at the address: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/57cf753a3f9b070c105bd2c1/operations/57cf753a3f9b070868a1f66f/console

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Content-Moderator/text-moderation-api says you can use it to "moderate text for profanity". Cocaine isn't a profanity. Why would you expect it to censor that?

Answer (score 2):

Cristian, Content Moderator's Text API is for filtering out profanity specifically and does not check for mention of drugs.

You can use the custom lists API to create your stop-words that the API will use to scan against in addition to the built-in list of terms.

See https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/57cf755e3f9b070c105bd2c2/operations/57cf755e3f9b070868a1f67f.

I would also appreciate knowing more about the sample terms that you felt should have been detected. Let's figure out a way to share those if that's all right with you.

Thanks!